# Upload script to SharePoint Online Web Part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, script, app-part

I have a web part that will render an existing report on Report Server. The way I found to do this, is to render the report in a App Part using `<iframe/>` and then reference the App Part in a web part using `<Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx" />`. However I will need to access the web part properties from the javascript. I'm trying to see if this is possible by using this function with a breakpoint on the 3rd line just to check if we were able to pull the properties:

```
function getWebPartProperties() {
    var object = $('#gordoWebPart');
    var properties = object.get_properties();
    var properties2 = object.get_properties();
}
```

And I'm referencing this script in my App Part using  `<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>`. The problem is that even though I can see the App.js loaded in my App Part (using IE developer tools), I can't see the script loaded on my web part.

Am I registering the script in the wrong way? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use querystrings to get the webpart properties, as used in this example:

```
<Content Src="~remoteAppUrl/AppPartContent.html?strProp=_strProp_&amp;intProp=_intProp_&amp;boolProp=_boolProp_&amp;enumProp=_enumProp_"
        Type="html"/>
```

Then you can get that from your javascript:
http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/3-ways-to-parse-a-query-string-in-a-url/

Have a look at this article, I have extracted the code from there:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921(v=office.15).aspx